# No sound in Ubuntu 17.04 after installing CUDA 8.0

Tags: ubuntu, audio, nvidia

[NO output device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wVjk2.png)

When I type

```
aplay -l
```

I get the following:

```
**** PLAYBACK 硬體裝置清單 ****
card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
子设备: 1/1
子设备 #0: subdevice #0
card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
子设备: 1/1
子设备 #0: subdevice #0
card 1: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: CX20751/2 Analog [CX20751/2    Analog]
子设备: 1/1
子设备 #0: subdevice #0
```

when I type

```
lspci | grep -i audio
```

I get

```
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor HD Audio Controller (rev 06)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset High Definition Audio Controller (rev 05)
```

Note that before I install cuda 8 with nVidia, my audio device worked perfectly. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: I'd suggest you add the output you receive as code, not as screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I haven't found a way to have both a working audio and working CUDA, so this certainly isn't the entire solution or fix but it's all I've managed to achieve. I've found a way to make the audio work again by downgrading the driver which unfortunately removes CUDA.

I also run Ubuntu 17.04 and I use GeForce GTX 660.

I had (or still have) the same problem as you. My audio was working fine. I wanted to use CUDA, so I typed

`nvcc`

(which is a CUDA compiler) into the terminal to see what happens. It said

`The program 'nvcc' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt install nvidia-cuda-toolkit`

So, I ran

`sudo apt install nvidia-cuda-toolkit`

After that, `nvcc` was present, it was able to compile a simple Hello World! program, but the GPU calls of the program did not work. So I rebooted the computer.

After the restart, the `nvcc` was working fine, but the audio was not. To be more specific, audio through the monitor (which is through HDMI and through GPU) was not working. Plugging the headphones into a jack directly to the computer worked ok.

What I did then, was that I went to `Additional Drivers` (found in the Dash). These were the available drivers for my GPU:

`Using NVIDIA legacy binary driver - version 304.135 from nvidia-304 (proprietary)
Using NVIDIA binary driver - version 340.102 from nvidia-340 (open source)
Using NVIDIA binary driver - version 375.82 from nvidia-375 (open source)
Using NVIDIA binary driver - version 378.13 from nvidia-378 (open source)
Using NVIDIA binary driver - version 381.22 from nvidia-381 (open source)
Using NVIDIA binary driver - version 384.69 from nvidia-384 (open source)
Using X.Org X server - Nouveau display driver from xserver-xorg-video-nouveau (open source)`

The open source v. 384 driver was selected.

I then tried to switch to the other drivers. For each driver, I selected it, clicked `Apply Changes`, let it install and restarted the computer.

With the open source v. 384 and v. 375 (v. 378 and v. 381 probably do the same) drivers the audio didn't work. But, with the proprietary v. 304 or open source v. 340 driver, the audio did work. The X.Org Nouveau driver did not work at all (bad resolution, could not pass through the login screen).

But everytime you change the driver, CUDA is removed, `nvcc` completely disappears.

The bad news is that when you then install CUDA again (by `sudo apt install nvidia-cuda-toolkit`) the driver is (after restart) set back to v. 384. So you have to choose between CUDA and working audio or reinstall the driver every time you want to use the other of these two although that could be a bit impractical.

The possible solutions to this could be somehow making the audio work in the 384 version or installing CUDA with the older driver (340 or 304 or some other version with working audio). I wasn't able to achieve any of those two.